# What could be a word or phrase to call someone annoying in a likeable way?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase (for a friend) who is annoying but in a good likeable way.

Comment: Unclear.  Can you give an example?

Comment: When someone tries to annoy you in a cute and adorable way meaning no offence.

Comment: Broadly, "tease" and how is that not pure vocabulary or style choice?

Comment: Vandit Goel  Sorry, I am drawing a blank.  I don't find a deliberate attempt to annoy me as cute or adorable, just offensive.  The only words or phrases I can think of are:  pester, being a  PIA, childish, annoying, other such like words.  I am probably just too old to help on this question.